# String cropping in Bash

Tags: bash, string

Suppose I have a string in my variable as follows.

```
var="/fnxn/ngfdg/abc.ext"
```

I can get the root of this variable (remove extension .*) as follows

```
echo ${var%.*}
```

I can get the tail of this variable (removing the path */) as follows

```
echo ${var##*/}
```

But now I have to remove both the path and the extension. I can do it in two step using another variable as follows.

```
var2=${var##*/}
var3=${var2%.*}
```

But the single step option (similar to zsh syntax below) shows an error message "bad substitution" in bash.

```
echo ${${var##*/}%.*}
```

It would be useful if I get a single step comprehensible option to reduce the code length and avoid additional environment variable.

Comment: You can't in any modern Bourne-like shell but `zsh`, which allow you to do nested parameter substitution.

Comment: I am not focusing on "nested parameter substitution", but cropping head and tail of a string in single step.

Comment: "it can significantly reduce the code length and memory usage" **[citation needed]** (if you're worried about the number of environment variables, you can re-use them: `var2=${var##*/}; var2=${var2%.*}`).

Comment: I withdraw the statement.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a fixed extension, [POSIX `basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html) supports exactly the cropping you're attempting:

```
basename "$var" .ext
```

---

If you don't, [zsh expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-GLOB_005fSUBST_002c-toggle) supports exactly what you're trying:

> If a ${...} type parameter expression or a $(...) type command substitution is used in place of name above, it is expanded first and the result is used as if it were the value of name. Thus it is possible to perform nested operations: ${${foo#head}%tail} substitutes the value of $foo with both ‘head’ and ‘tail’ deleted.

So in zsh

```
echo ${${var##*/}%.*}
```

will do what you expected.

---

If you're committed to Bash, and you want to save lines, you could use sed:

```
sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//' <<<"${var##*/}"
```

That's just a regular-expression replacement of everything after the last `.` with nothing, after losing the prefix the same way you are now. I don't see this particularly saving memory over the two-line version, however, and it's probably less comprehensible too.

Note that there's no reason you can't use the same variable right through the process:

```
var2=${var##*/}
var2=${var2%.*}
```

The expansion happens before the assignment, so this is safe. If your concern is a really long filename being stored twice, that won't happen now, but I don't think that is a realistic problem.

Comment: Yes, I prefer BASH.

Comment: If you want to save lines, just write both substitutions on one line, it's still shorter than the sed (and more readable perhaps)...

Comment: In `zsh`, `$var:t:r` (like in `csh`) would be enough.

Comment: @gibies, by writing those variable expansions unquoted in your question, you actually used `zsh` syntax, not `bash`.

Comment: Note that the `sed` one assumes the variable doesn't contain newline characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas got your points. The question is edited based on your comment on syntax.

Comment: @gibies, what I meant is that `echo ${var%.*}` is `zsh` syntax. [In `bash`, you need: `echo "${var%.*}"`](/q/171346/). (well, strictly speaking, that would be [`printf '%s\n' "${var%.*}"`](/q/65803) (in `zsh` as well)).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The echo is working without quotes at least in my bash terminal. I usually avoid quotes in my shell scripts unless it is essential.

Comment: @gibies, omitting the quotes is invoking the split+glob operator in bash and most other Bourne-like shells. Curly brackets are generally only cosmetic, the quotes are necessary. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls, or any of these Q&A here: [1](/q/171346), [2](/q/68694), [3](/q/131766), [4](/q/131766), [5](/q/78914)... Try for instance with `var='foo/bar * baz'` with the default value of `$IFS`. Compare with `zsh`.

Comment: The curly bracket protects the variable name from attachment string. `echo ${var}_attachment_string` give the expected output while `echo $var_attachment_string` search for a variable name "var_attachment_string". Hence a habit of using curly bracket is better to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Similarly in the absence of curly bracket `%.*` is treated as a string to be attached to the value in the variable. `ls ${var%.*}.*` have `.*` with two different meaning. One inside curly bracket is the string manipulator associated with `%` and one outside it is a wild character associated with `ls` command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44623/discussion-between-gibies-and-stephane-chazelas).